# Java FX 'cannot find symbol'

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-14

I'm new to java and java fx, I am trying to create a simple window but I keep getting the error

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Group
  location: class sample.Main
```

This is my code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }




}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't importing [`javafx.scene.Group`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html). Add

```
import javafx.scene.Group;
```

Comment: Thankyou, (Its not letting me accept it as the answer yet)